# PHP sort table when submit button is clicked

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, html-table

I want to be able to sort my table as ASC in a field when the submit button is clicked.

I have used an array function to get the information from a SQL database, I have tried making a sort function but when I click 'submit' nothing happens.

This is my attempt of creating the submit button:

```
 <h1> Courses </h1>
<form name="Table Properties" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Order by Week
<button type="submit" name="week" class="button" <?php echo $value='1'; ?>"> Sort Week </button>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['week'])){
        $query="SELECT * FROM `classes` ORDER BY `classes`.`week` ASC";
   }
```

When I click submit the table remains the same.

Here is my table connect information

```
$con = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");
if (!$con) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("username", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `classes`";
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th> Name 1 </th>
<th> Name 2 </th>
<th> Name 3 </th>
<th> Name 4 </th>
</tr>";
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 1'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['week'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 3'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 4'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

I asked a similar question in the past but I think they misunderstood due to lack of full information.

Comment: I don't see anywhere you are executing your SQL order by week.

Comment: It's at the top. The second half of my code displays the table as it is. I want the user to be able to see the table and then if they want to order it they can click a button.

Comment: You are just defining the query, but never running it

Comment: Well if you could direct me to a website that teaches you how to run scripts via buttons that would be most helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
$con = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");
if (!$con) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("username", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `classes`";

if(isset($_POST['week'])){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `classes` ORDER BY `classes`.`week` ASC";
   }

$myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th> Name 1 </th>
<th> Name 2 </th>
<th> Name 3 </th>
<th> Name 4 </th>
</tr>";
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 1'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['week'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 3'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 4'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to alter your original query.
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM classes";`

Let's summarize :

Your form :

```
<h1> Courses </h1>
<form name="Table Properties" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Order by Week
<button type="submit" name="week" class="button" <?php echo $value='1'; ?>"> Sort Week </button>
</form>
```

When you submit :

```
<?php

$orderString = ''; // default 
if (isset($_POST['week'])){
    $orderString = "`classes`.`week` ASC";
}
```

Your display :

```
$con = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");
if (!$con) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("username", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `classes`";
// now check order
if ($orderString !== '') {
    // Concatenate
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . $orderString;
}
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th> Name 1 </th>
<th> Name 2 </th>
<th> Name 3 </th>
<th> Name 4 </th>
</tr>";
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 1'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['week'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 3'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $record['name 4'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ORDER BY` clause to the SQL statement in the "table connect information".

Comment: Would that make the table displayed ordered? I want the table unordered at first, as it is being displayed on, and then when they click the submit button it will order.

Answer (score 0):

You define your action, when the submit button is pressed, but don't actually use it. You don't need the `php` part after your form.
Try to edit your table connect information:

```
...
mysql_select_db("username", $con);
if(isset($_POST['week'])){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `classes` ORDER BY `classes`.`week` ASC";
}
else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `classes`";
}
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);
...
```